# PostgreSQL: Save query results to file and get number of saved rows, windows/odbc

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to save query results to text file automatically, without looping through reader object in VB.NET with using ODBC windows connection.
But I can't find how!

That's what I try so far:

```
mCmd = New OdbcCommand( _
"SELECT my_id FROM " & myTable & " WHERE myflag='1' \o 'c:/a_result.txt'", mCon)
n = mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

But that don't work at all.
Please advice or code example how to get it.

And second...
It will be ideally that with saving results to text I get a number of saved rows in variable 'n'.
As for now I get only 0 or 1 depends if query was successful or not.

EDIT:
After some fighting I found a way for do this with more or less success.
To txt file:

```
mCmd = New OdbcCommand( _
"COPY (SELECT my_id FROM " & myTable & " WHERE myFlag='1' " & _
"ORDER BY my_id) TO 'c:/a_result.txt' DELIMITER AS '|'", mCon)
```

To csv file:

```
mCmd = New OdbcCommand( _
"COPY (SELECT my_id FROM " & myTable & " WHERE myFlag='1' " & _
"ORDER BY my_id) TO 'c:/a_result.csv' WITH CSV", mCon)
```

That works, but I am not able to escape quotes and '\' so I got double signs in output file.
If someone with experience know how to achieve escaping and changing delimiter for csv files I would be glad to see it on given example.

Variable 'n' after query contain a number of exported rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\o` sequence is a [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-psql.html) meta-command. That means it is a feature of `psql`. If you want this functionnality you will have to implement it in your client. It is very easy though.

Comment: This question is targeted to people which think that "it is very easy". However, it is not for me what is main reason why I found SO as one useful community.