# Postgresql, query results to new table

Tags: postgresql

Windows/NET/ODBC

I would like to get query results to new table on some handy way which I can see through data adapter but I can't find a way to do it.
There is no much examples around to satisfy beginner's level on this.
Don't know temporary or not but after seeing results that table is no more needed so I can delete it 'by hand' or it can be deleted automatically.

This is what I try:

```
  mCmd = New OdbcCommand("CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 ON COMMIT DROP AS " & _
  "SELECT dtbl_id, name, mystr, myint, myouble FROM " & myTable & " " & _
  "WHERE myFlag='1' ORDER BY dtbl_id", mCon)

  n = mCmd.ExecuteNonQuery
```

*This run's without error and in 'n' I get correct number of matched rows!!*

But with pgAdmin I don't see those table no where?? No matter if I look under opened transaction or after transaction is closed.
Second, should I define columns for temp1 table first or they can be made automatically based on query results (that would be nice!).

Please minimal example to illustrate me what to do based on upper code to get new table filled with query results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter way to do the same thing your current code does is with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE AS SELECT ...` . See the [entry for `CREATE TABLE AS` in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html).

Temporary tables are **not** visible outside the session ("connection") that created them, they're intended as a temporary location for data that the session will use in later queries. If you want a created table to be accessible from other sessions, don't use a `TEMPORARY` table.

Maybe you want `UNLOGGED` (9.2 or newer) for data that's generated and doesn't need to be durable, but must be visible to other sessions?

See related: [Is there a way to access temporary tables of other sessions in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5236/is-there-a-way-to-access-temporary-tables-of-other-sessions-in-postgres)

Comment: Did this mean that table temp1 was created with columns from query and I just can't see it but I can get results before "END TRANSACTION"?

Comment: @user973238 Session, not transaction. You can `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` and still have access to a `TEMPORARY` table unless you created it as `ON COMMIT DROP`. *Other sessions ("connections")* cannot access the temporary table at *any time*, before or after transaction end.

Comment: Ok, understand now a bit better, thank you. Now I try showed query and export temp1 after that in csv file. Works! This is really nice and very fast option to create and fill a table without defining it's columns!

Comment: @user973238 If all you're trying to do is create a CSV file, with most client drivers you'd just use the `COPY` command and let the server do the work. psqlODBC doesn't seem to support server-to-client `COPY`, though. I have to wonder why you're using psqlODBC rather than nPgSQL though.  nPgSQL supports `COPY`; see http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/apidocs/Npgsql.NpgsqlCopyOut.html . With ODBC you can always use server-side `COPY` to make the file on the server if your application has access to a location writeable by the DB server.

Comment: No, I create csv file just for see my temp1 table, I learned this yesterday :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14010974/postgresql-save-query-results-to-file-and-get-number-of-saved-rows-windows-odb. I uses ODBC instead of npgsql because I can't get it to work! As for now this goes fine.